# How to convert image byte array generated by zkteco-slk20r scanner into bmp file

Tags: java

I am trying to convert "regTemp" byte array to bmp file after `DBMerge(long dbHandle , byte[] temp1, byte[] temp2, byte[] temp3, byte[] regTemp, int[] regTempLen)` *(This function is used to combine registered fingerprint templates and returns the result in regTemp)* generates the final byte array.

**I found many answers in stackoverflow but so far no luck, Some-Answers:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60769564/9044234

*-Gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2048 out of bounds for length 2048*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193769/9044234

*-Gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!*

**`You can find whole source code and documentation here:`** https://github.com/sayednaweed/slk20r-zkteco-java-sample

```
public class ZKFPDemo extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea textArea;
    //pre-register template
    private byte[][] regtemparray = new byte[3][2048];
    private long mhDB = 0;

    private void OnExtractOK(byte[] template, int len){
           int[] _retLen = new int[1];
           _retLen[0] = 2048;
           byte[] regTemp = new byte[_retLen[0]];

           if(0 == (ret = FingerprintSensorEx.DBMerge(mhDB, 
              regtemparray[0], regtemparray[1], regtemparray[2], 
              regTemp, _retLen))){
                   // Here I want to convert regTemp to bmp.
                   textArea.setText("Merged successfully.");

    }else{

                   textArea.setText("Failed to merge.");

    }
  }
}
```

**I used this fingerprint scanner in C# project with C# SDK using follwoing code I was able to to convert it to BitmapSource then displayed the image.**

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(byte[] buffer)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmap = null;

        if (buffer != null && !(buffer.Length < 10))
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
                    stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

It's been days, I am unable to solve the issue please someone help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Both answers that you mentioned are exactly the same method that is not in the code in the question. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question.

Comment: I just updated the question what approach should I use to overcome the issue.